# Как отловить событие мыши?

Tags: javascript

Надо сделать, чтобы когда мы не находимся на (`.navigation-link` или `.navigation-list`) только тогда событие удалялось. Подскажите, как это реализовать?

```js
'use strict';

const linkElements = document.querySelectorAll('.navigation-link'),
   listItem = document.querySelector('.navigation-list');

for (let i = 0; i < linkElements.length; i++) {
  const element = linkElements[i],
    x_pos = element.offsetWidth / 2 + element.offsetLeft,
    y_pos = element.offsetTop + element.offsetHeight / 2,
    translate = 'translate(' + x_pos + 'px, ' + y_pos + 'px)',
    scale = 'scale(' + element.offsetWidth + ', ' + element.offsetHeight + ')',
    underline = document.querySelector('.underline')
    // console.log(element.getBoundingClientRect());
    underline.style.transform = 'translate(446.5px, 27px) ' +  'scale(45, 20)';

 element.addEventListener('mouseenter', (e)=> {
    if (e.target || e.currentTarget === listItem) {
      underline.style.transform = translate + ' ' + scale;
      underline.classList.add('animation-outline');
      console.log(translate + ' ' + scale);
    }
  });
    
}
```

```css
.right-side {
    width: 65%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.underline {
    position: absolute;
    top: 38px;
    left: 0;
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.33, 1.61, 0, 0.83);
}

.animation-outline {
 background-color: #E4D442;
}

.navigation, .navigation-list {
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: 52px;
}

.navigation-list {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100%;
}

.navigation-item {
    margin-right: auto;

    &:last-child {
        margin-right: 0;
    }
}

.navigation-link {
   font-size: 18px;
   line-height: 1.6;
   font-weight: 400;
   color: #fff;
   position: relative;
  padding: 10px 0;

   &:hover {
       &:before {
           width: 100%;
       }
   }
}
```

```html
<div class="right-side">
    <div class="underline outline"></div>
    <nav class="navigation">
        <ul class="navigation-list">
            <li class="navigation-item">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="navigation-link">
                    About
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="navigation-item">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="navigation-link">
                    Features
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="navigation-item">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="navigation-link">
                    Reviews
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="navigation-item">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="navigation-link">
                    Blog
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="navigation-item">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="navigation-link">
                    Support
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <a href="javascript:(0);" class="btn-app">Get App</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const linkElements = document.querySelectorAll('.navigation-link'),
listItem = document.querySelector('.navigation-list');
for (let i = 0; i < linkElements.length; i++) {
  const element = linkElements[i],
    x_pos = element.offsetWidth / 2 + element.offsetLeft,
    y_pos = element.offsetTop + element.offsetHeight / 2,
    translate = 'translate(' + x_pos + 'px, ' + y_pos + 'px)',
    scale = 'scale(' + element.offsetWidth + ', ' + element.offsetHeight + ')',
    underline = document.querySelector('.underline')
    // console.log(element.getBoundingClientRect());
    underline.style.transform = 'translate(446.5px, 27px) ' +  'scale(45, 20)';

 element.addEventListener('mouseenter', (e)=> {
    if (e.target || e.currentTarget === listItem) {
      underline.style.transform = translate + ' ' + scale;
      underline.classList.add('animation-outline');
      console.log(translate + ' ' + scale);
    }
    element.addEventListener('mouseleave',(e)=>{
    underline.classList.remove('animation-outline');
  })
  });

}
```

```css
.right-side {
    width: 65%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.underline {
    position: absolute;
    top: 38px;
    left: 0;
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.33, 1.61, 0, 0.83);
}

.animation-outline {
 background-color: #E4D442;
}

.navigation, .navigation-list {
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: 52px;
}

.navigation-list {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100%;
}

.navigation-item {
    margin-right: auto;

    &:last-child {
        margin-right: 0;
    }
}

.navigation-link {
   font-size: 18px;
   line-height: 1.6;
   font-weight: 400;
   color: #fff;
   position: relative;
  padding: 10px 0;

   &:hover {
       &:before {
           width: 100%;
       }
   }
}
```

```html
<div class="right-side">
    <div class="underline outline"></div>
    <nav class="navigation">
        <ul class="navigation-list">
            <li class="navigation-item">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="navigation-link">
                    About
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="navigation-item">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="navigation-link">
                    Features
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="navigation-item">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="navigation-link">
                    Reviews
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="navigation-item">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="navigation-link">
                    Blog
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="navigation-item">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="navigation-link">
                    Support
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <a href="javascript:(0);" class="btn-app">Get App</a>
</div>
```